# Does Google Analytics influence Alexa rank?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, alexa

Do the statistics seen in Google Analytics influence how Alexa ranks a site?  Or does each service have its own rankings?

Comment: I realize that this is a very basic question with a very obvious answer, but that is not a reason to use a down vote.  When you use a down vote, you are also expected to leave a comment explaining your down vote.

Answer (score 6):

Google Analytics and Alexa have nothing to do with one another.

Alexa is a relatively meaningless metric which only shows an approximate traffic rank based on only users that have their browser toolbar/extension/site script installed. It can only measure statistics based on their own userbase so the real accuracy of Alexa ranking is considerably wayward.

[More information on how Alexa works](http://www.alexa.com/help/traffic-learn-more).